# ProgressDialog Issue (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-progressbar

I have this ProgressDialog:

```
private ProgressDialog pd;
```

I set this ProgressBar by doing this:

```
pd = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Loading...");
```

When this pops up, everything works fine but I can click and it goes away.
How do I make it so that it stays up even if I click on the screen?

Comment: try this `pd.setCancelable(false);`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the `.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);`

I recommend you use something else though, apparently `ProgressDialog` is deprecated since Android 8

Comment: I am using android 7, is there something wrong with that.

Comment: progressDialog is Deprecated for API 26 and higher. Instead of it you can use progressBar.